# Setting Global View Context For Core Data in SwiftUI (Bad?, Good?)

Tags: swiftui, core-data, crashlytics

Typically, we define `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context` in View, then we can get context from it.

My question is can I directly define a global context called `dbContext` in the below demo rather than having to declare it in every view? Is there any bad part of it excluding testing, like safety?

```swift
let dbContext = DependencyContainer.dbManager.container.viewContext // global context，main thread
class DbManager {
    static let shared = DbManager()
    private static let expiredDays = 30

    var container: NSPersistentContainer
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DB")
        container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
            if let error {
                DLog(message: "DB init error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I have some rare crash cases in Firebase, I'm not sure whether or not it's related to this?

[image]

Comment: BAD. As you have a singleton you can get the context everywhere *encapsulated*. The `@Environment` way is the recommended one, the singleton is actually not needed if the stack is created in the root view as `@StateObject`.

Comment: @vadian can it be a related root cause for my crash issue?

Comment: I have no idea, the crash seems to be more related to a too soon deallocated (Navigation) View Controller.